# How to use a decorator in Python to perform authentication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am implementing a Flask-RESTFul API where I receive a token from postman and compare it with the token I configured in my code as below:

```
file: functions.py

def authenticate():
    headers = flask.request.headers
    bearer = headers.get('Authorization')
    token = bearer.split()[1]
    try:
        if str(hashlib.md5(b'Token_String').hexdigest()) == token:
            logger.info('Token authentication successful.')
            return True
        else:
            logger.error('Token autherization failed. Please check the token supplied.')
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        if token is None:
            logger.info('Token cannot be null. Supply a token with API call.')
            return {'message': 'Token cannot be null. Exception: {error}'.format(error=e)}, 400
        else:
            logger.info('Token cannot be null. Supply a token with API call.')
            return {'message': 'Error reading token. Cannot be Null/Empty. Exception: {error}'.format(error=e)}, 400
```

This is my API's get method:

```
class APIClass(Resource):

    @classmethod
    def get(self):
        logger.info('Initiating get()')
        if fc.authenticate():
            run_some_sql_statements
        else:
            return {'message': 'Token authentication failed'}, 401
        pass
```

Instead of using an IF-Condition, is there a way I can use the method: `authenticate` from `functions.py` file as a decorator on top of my `get()`.

I tried doing this and faced the below error:

```
from validations import functions as fc     

@classmethod
@fc.authenticate
def get(self):
```

But I see a compilation error: `Function 'authenticate' lacks a positional argument`

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I made here and how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

The flask-restful docs contain a section about resource method decorators:
https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#resource-method-decorators

```py
class APIClass(Resource):
    method_decorators = [authenticate]
```

Comment: it's in the docs: `method_decorators = {'get': [cache]}`